# Get list of files present in the old branch not present in the new one?

Tags: git

In GIT when I switch from branch `branch-a` to `branch-b` how do I get the list of files that are present in `branch-b` but not in `branch-a` ?

I need this for a specific directory but once I've the list of all files I can filter myself. But if there is a way to get the list only for a specific directory is better.

Comment: `git diff branch-a..branch-b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:

```
git diff --name-only branch-a..branch-b  --diff-filter=A
```

You can list the files relative only to a directory with:

```
 git diff --name-only branch-a..branch-b  --diff-filter=A --relative=directory
```